# Excel conditional data validation without named tables?

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

I created a conditional data validation for my device groups using "named tables" like in the example shown here:

[image]

Then on cell B5, I went to data validation, selected list, and added formula =indirect(A5), to make a drop down list shown here:

[image]

...but what I want to do instead of creating tables for each group (IE Cisco, Juniper...), is have all the devices on column B and have data validation reference column A to determine which group the devices belongs to. Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this formula either as a named range or directly in data validation:

```
=INDIRECT("$B"&MATCH($C$1,$A:$A,FALSE)&":$B"&COUNTIF($A:$A,$C$1) +MATCH($C$1,$A:$A,FALSE)-1)
```

I have put the brand selection in C1 for the example, you can change it to A8 but then you also need to change the range from $A:$A to $A2:$A5.
The formula will also work as a spill formula directly on the page, if you put it in a cell with free cells beneath it then it automatically fills the matches below.

[image]